# Best architecture for designing a system with Redis & DBMS

Tags: java, architecture, redis

I have a web instance that provides huge amount of data with high traffic. I want to cache the all data by using Redis. I also want to keep updated my database. During the "select" request, the request will be sent to ony Redis. If the request is "update" or "delete" it will be sent both redis and db.

I decided to put a "request handler" layer (such as a web service, web instance, independent app with socket structure etc.) that handles all type of request and send them to the proper app (redis or DBMS). However, if I put that layer, I think, I cannot use the power of Redis very well. For example, if my request handler layer is down, the balance system and data keeping (minimum lost) skills of Redis becomes meaningless. On the other hand, Redis offers to handle so many concurrent requests, what about my "request handler" layer. The health of my system will be up to my request handler layer?

I just need your advices and ideas about the architecture of this kind of systems.

(user1, user2, user3 ... userN) ---> request handler ----> (Redis or/and DBMS)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is independant of Redis power.
If you have some different endpoint with data , you will have to route them correctly to redis and/or dbms. They not communicate on the same way so you should have routing and/or translating layer. But it's will not be a so smart layer . You can do something like this:

- on reading taking from redis if exist , if is not, taking from dbms ,store on redis, give back to the client
- on writing delete entry on redis and update on dbms

and you cans use the replication system on redis to get more powerful:

master redis linked to the dbms -> multiple redis slave to give back to the client

Answer (score 1):

Key points in your requirements are :

1. Huge amount of data which needs to be stored.
2. Select on redis, update/delete on redis and database.
3. Handler which can route messages to redis or database.

Application level requirements:

1. persistence
2. throughput
3. scaliblity

To achieve all the above points I would break up the application in 3 parts:

1. Producers (providing huge data)
2. Consumers (storing data on redis or database)
3. Message queue/broker accepting huge data, providing persistence and routing to consumers. (like RabbitMq)

With introduction of message queue we decouple producers and consumer. Both are unaware of existence of each other.

Assuming message queue as RabbitMQ, this how application will work further.

Producers publish messages on queues with some routing keys. Consumers are bind to queues with specific routing key. Consumer consumer messages with their routing key and perform their actions.

Routing keys could be like: select, update, delete

Consumers: RedisSelectConsumer, RedisUpdateDeleteConsumer, DatabaseUpdateDeleteConsumer

This way we have divided responsibilities among modules.

If there is a high rate of incoming messages increase the number of consumers.

Use replication in REDIS to have a fail-over in case master server is down.